# Notify for database change

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have 2 systems and it is lan based. I just want the other system to be notified when there's a change in the database. I am using C# and ms-access for the database. Can you please give me some ideas on how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using access, you can't write triggers as you could in MS SQL for example. There are different approachs. Some of them are:

1. On system 1, develop small web api with a method which will return true or false if system was changed. From system 2 ping system 1 API method on some interval.
2. Use SignalR, Microsoft technology for real time programming. Create SignalR client on system 2, and send message from system 1 to system 2 when change on database occures.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your database only from client (C# application) then it would be more appropriate to send the notification from your client (when changing data) rather than using a push model (e.g. trigger callback from database).

See the [StackExchange question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200399/automatically-observing-changes-in-database-tables).